# PHP: share cookie only between set of sub-domains (Production sub-domains & Staging sub-domains)

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

I have a site with its production url `www.mysite.com` & staging url `staging.mysite.com`, now I need to setup a set of sub-domains to be used by each environment like:

1. From `www0.mysite.com` to `www9.mysite.com` for *Production* environment
2. From `staging0.mysite.com` to `staging9.mysite.com` for *Staging* environment

So, how could I share the cookie between each set of sub-domains (per environment) without overlapping with the other set?

Note: if I used something like this in `php.ini` (or its equivelant in my code base):

> session.cookie_domain = ".mysite.com"

then the cookie will be shared between all 2 sets of sub-domains (production & staging)

Comment: If you're staging env is a +1 of production, then cookies in staging will be valid in prod (or not used) and cookies in prod will be valid in staging (or, again, not used).  Stick the generic (*.domain) and you should be fine :)

Comment: I'm affraid this is not possible to share cookie between some set of subdomains, while not sharing it with another set. You can only set a particular (sub)domain for cookie, regexes are not supported.

Comment: Ok I've got some idea, can you change domains from www0.mysite.com to 1.www.mysite.com, 2.www.mysite.com etc. ?

Comment: well @RobertTrzebiński , I know what you are getting up to :) , it is just will conflict with other configuration on my server (which will need me to solve the new configuration problem), & will cost me a new ssl certificate(s) for the new level of subdomains!

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I don't have any better idea to solve that :(